# mysql subqueries total between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I tried some subqueries but I didn't succed.

Let's suppose we have 2 tables : users(iduser, name), invoices(idinvoice, title, status, iduser)
and we want to show for each user, total invoices "paid", total invoices "unpaid" (that's status field)

I tried query like that

```
Select users.*, total_invoices_paid, total_invoices_unpaid
from users
LEFT JOIN (SELECT iduser, sum(if(status='paid',1,0)) AS total_invoices_paid, sum(if(status='unpaid',0,1)) AS total_invoices_unpaid 
           FROM invoices GROUP BY invoices.idinvoice) AS subinvoices
ON subinvoices.iduser=users.iduser
```

But I got wrong values, I think I missed something, but don't know what

any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select u.*,
    sum(i.status = 'paid') as total_invoices_paid,
    sum(i.status = 'unpaid') as total_invoices_unpaid
from users u
left join invoices i on u.iduser = i.iduser
group by u.iduser;
```

A boolean is evaluated to 1 or 0 for true or false respectively in MySQL. Hence, using `sum` on the condition, we can find count.

Using subquery:

```
select u.*,
    coalesce(i.total_invoices_paid, 0) as total_invoices_paid,
    coalesce(i.total_invoices_unpaid, 0) as total_invoices_unpaid,
    coalesce(i.total_invoices, 0) as total_invoices,
    coalesce(i.total_paid_and_unpaid, 0) as total_paid_and_unpaid,
    coalesce(i.total_with_non_null_status, 0) as total_with_non_null_status
from users u
left join (
    select iduser,
        sum(status = 'paid') as total_invoices_paid,
        sum(status = 'unpaid') as total_invoices_unpaid,
        count(1) as total_invoices,
        sum(status in ('paid','unpaid')) as total_paid_and_unpaid,
        count(status) as total_with_non_null_status
    from invoices
    group by iduser
    ) i on u.iduser = i.iduser
group by u.iduser;
```

Comment: GurV, I don't want using left join like that, as I have around millions of entries, and I have simplified the query, but there is other join with other tables, this is why I'm looking for subquery

Comment: I tried really doing "left join invoices i on u.iduser = i.iduser", but query took me around 20min to show . I doing already some other joins, so 
1000 users  10 roles  2 subusers * 100 invoices = 2 Millions of entries !

Comment: @Zeta - It mostly depends on the data. Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: it works good ! some total_invoices_paid / total_invoices_unpaid, return null value, can be 0 instead?

Comment: @Zeta - You can use `coalesce` for that. Updated

Comment: question, what is best way to calculate sum of both total_invoices_paid + total_invoices_unpaid, I do another sum line? If I do (total_invoices_paid + total_invoices_unpaid) and since I have null columns, I got problem

Comment: @Zeta Can the status column only have 'paid' and 'unpaid' value?

Comment: @Zeta - Do you want to include empty (null) in the count or exclude it? Updated the answer. Please check